# F# If-statement type mismatch errors

Tags: list, recursion, error-handling, f#, type-conversion

Im a relatively new F# programmer, and it seems everytime i fix one problem in my code another arises, so my issue is inside the transpose recursive function, i want to run an if-else statement inside it to check if the input is actually valid or not, however this errors and im not sure why or how to fix it.

I already have a question with quite a similar issue and title, however i was told to make a new question instead of editing the old one because of various reasons.

```
type Result<'T,'TError> =
    | Ok of 'T
    | Error of 'TError


let isValidTBL list =
    match List.map List.length list |> List.distinct |> List.length with
    | 1 -> true
    | _ -> false



let Column_1 list =
    if List.exists List.isEmpty list then [] // return empty list
    else
    list |> List.map List.head

let Column_2 list =
    if List.exists List.isEmpty list then
        Error "empty value"
    else
        list |> List.map List.tail |> Ok

let rec transpose list = [
  if (isValidTBL list = false) then Error "Invalid Table"
  else
  match list with
  | []::list -> () 
  | list -> 

        yield Column_1 list 
        yield! transpose (Column_2 list) ]
```

*warning FS0020: The result of this expression has type 'Result<'a,string>' and is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr |> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr'.*

*error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
''a list list'

but here has type
'Result<'b list list,string>'*

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue is that you are trying to mix `Result` with an ordinary F# `list`. When you are inside a list comprehension, you can only return values using `yield`, so when you write:

```ml
let rec transpose list = [
  if (isValidTBL list = false) then Error "Invalid Table"
  else 
    yield // (...)
]
```

The part with `Error "Invalid table"` is not a return value, but just a value you create and then ignore. This bit you could solve by rearranging the code to start the list comprehension only in the `Ok` case:

```ml
let rec transpose list =
  if (isValidTBL list = false) then Error "Invalid Table"
  else Ok [
    yield // (...)
  ]
```

However, this is also not solving all your problems because you want to have a recursive call to `transpose` and if this is also inside a comprehension, then it's "too late" to return an error.

You can write this without comprehensions, but to be honest, I think this gets a lot easier if you just handle the error using exceptions:

```
exception InvalidTable
exception EmptyValue 

let Column_2 list =
  if List.exists List.isEmpty list then raise EmptyValue
  else list |> List.map List.tail 

let rec transpose list = [
  if (isValidTBL list = false) then raise InvalidTable
  else
    match list with
    | []::list -> ()
    | list -> 
        yield Column_1 list 
        yield! transpose (Column_2 list) ]
```

You have to make sure to handle the exceptions and you may want to convert them to `Error`  values if you are using `Result` throughout your project, but the code becomes simpler this way.